How do I reliably format std::vector<bool> with fmt's range support?
I'm getting inconsistent behaviour trying to format a vector of bools across different environments:
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<bool> vec = {true, false, true};
    fmt::print("Vector contents: {}\n", vec);
    return 0;
}

This works fine in several environments:

Compiler Explorer: Clang 19.1.0
Compiler Explorer: GCC trunk
Compiler Explorer: Clang trunk

But fails on:

Local macOS (M1): Clang 19.1.1 clang++ -std=c++23 -I libraries/fmt/include
Compiler Explorer: Zig trunk

With this error:
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'fmt::detail::type_is_unformattable_for<std::vector<bool>, char>'

All tests use fmt from trunk and c++23.
What's causing this inconsistency and how can I fix it?

Local macOS (M1): Clang 19.1.1 clang++ -std=c++23 -I libraries/fmt/include which libc++ is bound?

libc++  19.1.1. what effect might that have?

How have you proved that and not AppleClang libc++ is used? The shown command does not prove that.

I sure have, otool shows me /nix/store/ljy5rwz4d540isx23sbq15dhz13pcd0h-libcxx-19.1.1/lib/libc++.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0

Where comrade 3C is going is, sure you have the right library and version, but is the program being linked to that library and version?

The otool output I shared shows the actual linked libraries in the binary by inspecting its linker sections, so /nix/store/.../libc++.1.0.dylib is the libc++ binary being linked.  This is a template instantiation error though so isn't it more likely to be an issue that occurs at compile-time not link-time?  Or am I missing something?

It probably doesn't matter but I'd use the latest released version of {fmt}, not trunk.

Unfortunately your instincts are right, I checked out the latest release and hit the same error with that build.

Side note: remember that std::vector<bool> is special. It doesn't hold bools and doesn't return bools. It holds a condensed version and returns proxy objects. That may or may not be relevant, but it's still a good thing to know.

Adding the fmt/std.h resolved the issue as it provides the formatter for the proxy type used by vector<bool>.
#include <fmt/std.h>

More details: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/4026
